# ¿Cómo borrar valores repetidos de una lista de tuplas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo `lista_original` que contiene tuplas con dos números que representan las coordenadas `x` e `y`.

**El problema es que se repiten muchos valores de la coordenada en 'y'** y lo que hice fue poner el `set` para eliminar los valores repetidos pero realmente lo que hace es borrar los valores que literalmente se repiten tanto en 'x' como en 'y' es decir ambos números.

Lo que quiero es borrar las tuplas que tengan el valor `y` repetido, es decir el segundo valor. Si el segundo valor se encuentra, borrar la tupla completa de la lista.

Pongo un **ejemplo de lo que tengo y me gustaría obtener**:

```
A = [(1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2),(4,4),(5,8)]
```

Resultado:

```
Valores de x = [3,4,5]
Valores de y = [2,4,8]
```

Con esto después quiero que genere un valor promedio de los valores que se repiten, porque lo que estoy haciendo es graficar esas coordenadas y lo que hace si no se hacer el "promedio" es graficar muchos puntos en esa área y es mejor tener como que un punto medio y no una gran mancha de puntos. **Esto es lo que estoy haciendo en mi código real.**

```
lista_original = [(151, 157), (203, 184), (204, 184), (219, 190), (220, 190), (221, 190), (222, 191), 
(237, 195), (238, 195), (239, 195), (240, 196), (241, 196), (254, 199), (255, 199), (256, 199), (257, 
200), (258, 200), (259, 200), (260, 200), (261, 200), (262, 200), (262, 201), (263, 201), (264, 201), 
(274, 202), (275, 202), (276, 202), (276, 203), (277, 203), (292, 204), (293, 204), (294, 204), (309, 
204), (310, 204), (311, 204), (312, 204), (313, 204), (327, 203), (328, 203), (329, 203), (330, 203), 
(331, 203), (348, 200), (349, 200), (350, 200), (389, 190)]

lista_diastema = set(lista_oscura_parabola)
print('VALORES DE PARABOLA NEGRA',list(lista_diastema))


diastemax = []
diastemay = []
for x, y in lista_diastema:
    diastemax.append(x)
    diastemay.append(y)

print('Valores de pixel diastema X',diastemax)
print('Valores de pixel diastema Y',diastemay)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create un `set()` o una `list()` donde vas guardando los valores que han aparecido, y asi puedes cribar.

```
lista_original = [(151, 157), (203, 184), (204, 184), (219, 190), (220, 190), (221, 190), (222, 191), 
(237, 195), (238, 195), (239, 195), (240, 196), (241, 196), (254, 199), (255, 199), (256, 199), (257, 
200), (258, 200), (259, 200), (260, 200), (261, 200), (262, 200), (262, 201), (263, 201), (264, 201), 
(274, 202), (275, 202), (276, 202), (276, 203), (277, 203), (292, 204), (293, 204), (294, 204), (309, 
204), (310, 204), (311, 204), (312, 204), (313, 204), (327, 203), (328, 203), (329, 203), (330, 203), 
(331, 203), (348, 200), (349, 200), (350, 200), (389, 190)]

repetidos_y = set()
lista_diastema = []
for x, y in lista_original:
    if y not in repetidos_y:
        repetidos_y.add(y)
        lista_diastema.append((x, y))

print(lista_diastema)
```

**Salida:**

```
[(151, 157), (203, 184), (219, 190), (222, 191), (237, 195),
(240,196), (254, 199), (257, 200), (262, 201), (274, 202),
(276, 203), (292, 204)]
```

### Explicación

1. Creamos la variable `repetidos_y` que almacenará cada segundo elemento de una tupla, y la variable `lista_diastema` que será la lista con las tuplas sin segundos elementos repetidos
2. `for x, y in lista_original:` Iteramos por la lista de valores
3. `if y not in repetidos_y:` verificamos si `y` se encuentra en `repetidos_y` si no se encuentra la añadimos a la lista de repetidos con el método `.add()` y después añadimos la tupla a `lista_diastema. En caso de si se encuentre, no hacemos nada y pasamos a la iteración siguiente.

Comment: Es correcto, justamente ese era lo que necesitaba. Gracias @Rubiales.